# 'display_formatter' attribute error in Python

Tags: python, error-handling, lda

I am working on a topic modelling script that uses the gensim package to create a model based on a collection of documents.

When preparing to visualise the model using the pyLDAvis package, I run into this error:

```
import pyLDAvis
pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/dev2.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyLDAvis.enable_notebook()
  File "/Users/username/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/pyLDAvis/_display.py", line 311, in enable_notebook
    formatter = ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/html']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_formatter'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `enable_notebook` function is only for when you are using the notebook. If you are writing a script that outputs a visualization as a HTML document then you don't need (and shouldn't) call that function. Rather I think all you will need to use is the prepare and [`save_html`](https://pyldavis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/API.html#pyLDAvis.save_html) functions.

Comment: Thanks! This is correct. Simply doing `visualisation = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda_model, corpus, dictionary)`, and then `pyLDAvis.save_html(visualisation, 'LDA_Visualization.html')` works!